# "AsyncFuture<T>" or what? Future<T> obtained in a background thread -- is it a pattern?

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns

I'd like to have some work done in a background thread as simple as creating a Future var for it and then asking later for the calculated value.

In pseudo-C#-code:

```
AsyncFuture<int> asyncFuture = new AsyncFuture<int>(FuncToCalculateValue);

//do some other work, or draw UI

if(asyncFuture.NoErrorsHappened){
   int realResult = asyncResult.Value;
}
```

I can implement such type by my own, but my question is: isn't that some kind of a known pattern? Is there maybe a name for it, or maybe even a framework implementation? Probably in .NET 4.0?

And if it is a pattern, what are the pitfalls associated with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yacoder, I really like [Ayende's two Future implementations](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/02/Its-the-future-now.aspx). There is some [good discussion](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/02/Its-the-future-now.aspx#20529) [from Jon Skeet](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/02/Its-the-future-now.aspx#20542) in the comments on the cons.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [Futures are part of the Task Parallel Library](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2008/02/29/7960146.aspx) which will be in .NET 4.0.

In .NET 4.0 Beta 1, it looks like this exists as a [`Task<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424(VS.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

also in Java the structure of the code using [Future is very similar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

You may be move the "do some other work or draw UI" as a parametric code? This can be viewed as a **Template Method**.